# Xamarin weird bug on Android Release build

Tags: android, xamarin

I have weird bug on Xamarin and I am about to lose my mind. My problem is my app package name "com.dnc.haber365" but after I build and check in logcat my application package name shows as "om.dnc.haber36" so it removes automatically first and last letter. However I am trying another package names but it works normally there is no problem. Because of this difference my app crashes immediately. I have Admob ,my app package name should exactly "com.dnc.haber365" the only name which I cant set.
[My Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS2Kj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clear your cache?

If you want to see this topic click [How to Clear catch data of my application programmatically in Xamarin android mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286373/how-to-clear-catch-data-of-my-application-programmatically-in-xamarin-android-mo)