# How to clear cache directory in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

When a user takes a photo I temporarily store the photo within my cache, and I haven't got a way to clear cache so this is going to cause problems later on, I've looked online as well as Microsoft's documentation but have not found anything.

```cs
var newFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, result.FileName); // Creates a file within cache 
using (var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync())
using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile)) // overwrites the file with the image
    await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

var cacheDir = FileSystem.CacheDirectory;
File.Delete(newFile); // thought this wwould delete the temp file but it doesn't
```

Comment: Do you get any exception or error?

Comment: No, with this code, no error and nothing seems to be deleted as the cache keeps going up and doesn't stay the same after taking a photo and storing it

Comment: Try this: This would delete all the files existing in the cache directory. It goes one step further of what you want. 
```var cacheDir = FileSystem.CacheDirectory;
            string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(cacheDir);
            foreach(string oneFile in allFiles)
            {
                if (File.Exists(oneFile))
                    File.Delete(oneFile);
            }```

Comment: That code is similar to my current except it tries to delete all the files in cache but after trying the code and running the app and then checking the storage of the app, the cache size is still increasing and hasn't decreased, so for some reason that code doesn't work?

Comment: But if you check that Directory, are there any files there? Because maybe the cache size is increasing and has nothing to do with your function. You could also use other path, like the FileSystem.AppDataDirectory

Comment: Sorry, how would I check the directory? I tried the other AppDataDirectory but when I check the app settings the cache is still increasing

Comment: You could check the directory manually, navigating through the files on your device. Or check if the method `Directory.GetFiles(cacheDir);` returns anything. If the folder is empty, then the cache directory has nothing to do with the cache you want to clear

Comment: okay so I checked and there is something in cache after clearing and then taking a photo and then checking if the cache is empty so I don't think the code has worked :(

Comment: It should be the same using the CacheDirectory or the AppDataDirectory or any other folder. Maybe the cache comes from another part of the code. For example, ImagesSource can use cache for internet downloaded images. This memory gets clear after certain time. In most of the cases, it should be handled automatically.

Comment: For android,you could use System.IO to delete the file like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44295289/10768653.